# form.deleteItem() results in 'Failed to edit the form. Please wait and try again'

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a need to re-use a specific form URL consistently while maintaining the ability to regenerate the form with script. To accomplish that, I wrote a function to delete form data. Initially, I had it running form.getItems() and was seeing the error in the topic. Thinking that it's because I'm not a programmer and my code is likely terribly inefficient, I re-wrote the routine to break out each itemType and a delay between each item deletion. This makes the routine incredibly slow for me, but I can deal with slow if it will make Google allow it to work.

Here is the code I have currently, and unfortunately, it's still giving me the same error. Is my issue actually a back end issue of Google's??? Is it my code? Both?

I have global variables for the form information:

```
var formurl='*a url that works for me*'
var form=FormApp.openByUrl(formurl);

function DeleteFormItems() {
  var formcheckboxitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX);
  var formdateitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.DATE);
  var formdatetimeitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.DATETIME);
  var formdurationitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.DURATION);
  var formgriditems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.GRID);
  var formimageitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.IMAGE);
  var formlistitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
  var formmultiplechoiceitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
  var formpagebreakitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK);
  var formparagraphtextitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT);
  var formscaleitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.SCALE);
  var formsectionheaderitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.SECTION_HEADER);
  var formtextitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.TEXT);
  var formtimeitems=form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.TIME);
  for (var i = formcheckboxitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formdateitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formdatetimeitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formdurationitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formgriditems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formimageitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formlistitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formmultiplechoiceitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formparagraphtextitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formscaleitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formsectionheaderitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formtextitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formtimeitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
  for (var i = formpagebreakitems.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Utilities.sleep(2000)
    form.deleteItem(i);
  };
}
```

Here is my updated script, where I'm still experiencing the error mentioned in the subject, but it makes more progress(deletes several items) before it gets the message.

```
var formurl='*a url that works for me*'
var form=FormApp.openByUrl(formurl);

function DeleteFormItems() {
  var formitems=form.getItems();
Logger.log('There are '+formitems.length+' total form items');
  for (var i = 1; i <= formitems.length-1; i++) {
    Utilities.sleep(2500)
    form.deleteItem(formitems[i]);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hey Man I finally found a workaround to the same problem. Try this:

```
function clearForm(F){
   //var F = FormApp.openById("your form")
   var items= F.getItems().length;
   while(F.getItems().length!=0){        
     try{      
      F.deleteItem(0);
      } catch(error)
      {Logger.log(error);
      }
  }
}
```

It threws no error and it fully cleans the form. I don't honnestly know why "while" works better than "For" it seems that it doesn't double-access it as the for does.

Hope it works perfect for you!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script

Comment: I suggest changing the deleteItem line to `F.deleteItems(F.getItems().length-1))`. This prevents a error when you are trying to delete a non-empty PageBreakItem

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same error. I finally figured out that the List and Multiple Choice items I had created which were assigned to "Go to page based on answer." were the problem. To fix it, I first removed the choices from every List and Multiple Choice item I wanted to delete, and then deleted these items. I lastly deleted all the other items. So far this has not given me the error anymore.

```
function deleteTheFreakinForm(myForm){

  //First, remove list item choices. Then delete the list items.

  var listItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);

  while(itemIndex < listItems.length){
    listItems[itemIndex].asListItem().setChoiceValues(['']);
    form.deleteItem(listItems[itemIndex]);
    itemIndex++;
  }

  //Second, remove the multiple choice item choices. Then delete the multiple 
  //choice items.

  var multipleChoiceItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
  itemIndex=0;
  while(itemIndex < multipleChoiceItems.length){
    multipleChoiceItems[itemIndex].asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(['']);
    form.deleteItem(multipleChoiceItems[itemIndex]);
    itemIndex++;
  }

  //Finally, delete the remaining form items.

  var items = form.getItems();
  itemIndex=0;
  while(itemIndex < items.length){
    form.deleteItem(items[itemIndex]);
    itemIndex++;
  }
}
```